# Windows 8 not booting from grub 2

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I have done a fair amount of research, and started of by disabling the secure booting UEFI settings as well as the Intel Smart boot. I partitioned the drive accordingly and when I restarted the computer it booted straight to ubuntu (which was to be expected) and after a boot-repair grub2 was working fine and showed the options for Windows 8. However, after selecting the Win8 option, my machine just hangs up at the loading screen with Sager logo. I have tried multiple resolves to no avail.

The Complete Log URL is:http://paste.ubuntu.com/5686995/

Update: I removed my second efi partition and windows is still stuck. I have tried bcdrrepair and chkdsk. I tried doing a repair with windows disk but it didnt work. I edited the grub file and manually put in a custom entry with a chainloader that should work and still no progress. When I boot it goes straight to windows RE. I check the windows syslog and get a message: a patch is preventing the system from starting up. I also tried a different bootloader suggest by a comment and the same problem occurs.

I have a 750gb mechanical drive (SDA1) and a 256 msata (boot)

Comment: Your log is incomplete. Please indicate your complete Boot-Info ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info )

Answer (score 0):

You haven't messed anything up with the partitions, it's just that Grub has trouble chainloading Windows under EFI. Try to get to your Windows OS from the laptop boot menu, for Sager I think you press F12 when booting.

Comment: I messed around with it a little bit and now it is getting past that sager logo, but when it gets to windows it goes straight to the whole Automatic Repair screen which just wants me to reformat my disk. Can't get into the actual windows environment or do much of anything... Any thought as to how I might fix that?

Comment: Try to follow up on [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/how-the-windows-8-automatic-repair-feature-works/7335) on how to locate the automatic repair log file; if you know where it is you can get to it from an Ubuntu session too, and you can either look for clues in it or post it here or in pastebin, so others can look into it.

Comment: Oh I can see now how you messed with the partitions, you have two EFI marked partitions reported by parted -l, sdb2 and sdb5, can you look into it? Perhaps you should mark sdb5 as something else, not EFI.

Comment: Thanks!! I am hoping that's it.. I will check tonight. What do you suggest I mark it as?

Comment: With gparted I would remove all flags, especially the boot flag, or with gdisk I would change the partition type code to 0700 - Microsoft basic data, since it is formatted FAT32.

Comment: I removed the second efi partition that I had and also removed the flags and it is still getting hung up at the windows RE mode. The new log is http://paste.ubuntu.com/5683467/. Sorry to keep bugging you but can you see anything wrong with this one?

Comment: I still don't get what is your sda device used for, and the error in line 81 /dev/sda1 ends after the last sector of /dev/sda. The device sda has a size of 750GB however the partition sda has a declared size of 2TB (4,294,967,295 sectors). Is this the drive that Windows RE wants to format? What's on it as of now?

Comment: sda is just my second drive. I have a ssd 256 and mech of 750. It is just a storage device and I believe its formatted for ntfs. There is nothing on it I believe its almost completely empty.

Comment: I would still try to fix the inconsistency between the sda1 declared number of sectors and sda actual size. On the other hand, could you try the tools at the Windows RE command prompt, such as chkdsk, even a BCD rebuild might help. For others with this error booting into Last good known configuration worked.

Comment: I never touched the sda partition so i dont know why it would be off. I tried bcdrepair and chkdsk both of which failed. And I had no saved checkpoints so system return wont work, i got to installing ubuntu pretty quick after I got my laptop.

Comment: This site recommends switching to chat when the comments section gets too large. A more detailed description on how chkdsk and bcd rebuild failed would certainly help, also the windows syslog, maybe a 'diskpart detail disk' output.

Comment: I dont have enough reputation for chat :( BCD rebuild said it completed successfully but it didnt fix the problem. Chkdsk said there were a few bad files but when i tried to run chkdsk \f it said it couldnt fix it because it was write protected. The syslog from the Windows Diagnosis says: A patch is preventing the system from starting

Comment: Google for this particular error (a patch is preventing...), people suggest to remove a file (pending.xml), though I don't think you did Windows updates at the same time with your Ubuntu install. Did BCD rebuild find an OS when you say it completed successfully? Can you access the [Safe mode](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-boot-into-windows-8-safe-mode/) option before it automatically enters RE? Which partition did you run chkdsk on, normally it should ask you to unmount it before performing the check. Too bad you can't go to chat yet, maybe posting in a forum would do.

Comment: I cannot reach safe mode. I also don't believe it found an os... (got a message saying 0 Os found) and maybe that's why it was write protected.. I will look into the BCDrepair and checkdsk a little more. I was also wondering if my second harddrive could be an issue.. do I need any efi partition for that?? Any more suggestions?

Comment: Make sure you are booting under EFI while doing all this, otherwise Windows will not work with the GPT partitions. Before erasing sdb5 did you check whether it was empty? For more BCD howto's read also [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader).

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) in Linux. Using the Debian package should set everything up to work correctly with no further effort, although you might want to remove some entries later. With any luck, rEFInd will boot either Windows or Linux with no problems.

Comment: I have no Idea what the problem is but I installed it and the menu came up when i booted my computer but  when i booted windows it went straight to windows recovery thing which still doesnt let me boot into windows. I can access my windows partition from ubuntu and windows was working fine before the install so i dont think i corrupted anything.. The syslog from the Windows Diagnosis says: A patch is preventing the system from starting.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Windows error messages, but that sounds as if there might be a pending software update for Windows that's gone wrong. I recommend either running a Windows recovery utility (but be careful, since they like to trash everything and restore the hard disk to a Windows-only configuration) or call Microsoft for help.